# Named parameters in Ruby don't work?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I wonder why named parameters don't work as I expect.

```
 def my_method(var1, var2 = 1, var3 = 10)
   puts var1, var2, var3
 end

my_method(999, var3 = 123)
```

The output

```
999
123
10
```

instead of (at least, as I guess should be):

```
999
1
123
```

So, what should I do to use named parameters?

**P.S.** When I use the hash, it's not what I'm looking for yet:

```
def my_method(var1, vars = {var2: 1, var3: 10} )
   puts var1, vars[:var2], vars[:var3]
 end

my_method(999, var3: 123)

999

123


my_method(999, var2: 111, var3: 123)

999
111
123



my_method(999)
999
1
10
```

So I have to override each value of `vars` or don't override them at all. Is there any more convenient way?

Comment: What ruby version are you using? There are no named parameters in 1.9.3 and older.

Comment: 1.9 doesn't have named parameters, they're in 2.x

Comment: Yes, I know. But what does `my_method(999, var3 = 123)` mean?

Comment: It calls my_method with the arguments 99 and 123 and sets the local (to the caller) variable var3 to 123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby `my_method(999, var3 = 123)` means, assign `var3` the value `123` and pass it to `my_method`.

There is no concept of named parameters, however, you can use a hash as an argument to `my_method` such as:

```
def my_method(args = {})
   p "#{args[:a]}, #{args[:b]}, #{args[:c]}"
end
```

Then you can call it with:

```
my_method(b: 2, c: 3, a: 1)
```

which will print `1, 2, 3`, because `b: 2, c: 3, a: 1` is inferred to be a hash by ruby. You can explicitly indicate the hash as well with:

```
my_method({b: 2, c: 3, a: 1})
```

Comment: How do I set default values for `args` then?

Comment: One technique used is to give default values within the function (in your case `my_method`) as in: `args[:a] = args[:a] || 3` for instance.

Comment: do you mean `args[:a] ||= 3`?

Comment: thanks. Is there any other technique?

Comment: You can mix an parameters, some could be hashes, others regular params. However, if you do that ambiguity may creep in, and you will need to explicitly use the curly brackets. Overloading is another option of course.

Comment: Can you show me an example please?

Comment: I like this approach for default values for a Hash parameter: `args.merge({ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 })`. Example: `{ a: 2 }.merge({ a: 1, b:1 }) #=> { a:2 b:1 }`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, Ruby does not have keyword arguments (yet, they are coming in 2.0). To achieve what you are trying to do, an `options` hash is a very common Ruby idiom.

```
def my_method(var1, options = {})
  var2 = options.fetch(:var2, 1)
  var3 = options.fetch(:var3, 10)

  puts var1, var2, var3
end

my_method(999)
# => 999, 1, 10

my_method(999, var3: 123)
# => 999, 1, 123

my_method(999, var2: 111)
# => 999, 111, 10

my_method(999, var2: 111, var3: 123)
# => 999, 111, 123

my_method()
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Note that using `options.fetch(:key, default)` rather than `options[:key] || default` is frequently preferable because it allows you to explicitly specify falsy values (ie `false` and `nil`).

```
options = {x: nil, y: false}

x = options[:x] || 42      # sets x to 42
x = options.fetch(:x, 42)  # sets x to nil

y = options[:y] || 43      # sets y to 43
y = options.fetch(:y, 43)  # sets y to false

z = options[:z] || 44      # sets z to 44
z = options.fetch(:z, 44)  # sets z to 44
```

You can even pass a block to `fetch` which allows you to defer computation of the default value:

```
options.fetch(:x) { some_expensive_calculation }
# some_expensive_calculation is only called if necessary
```

Comment: I think you have a couple of typos in your third code block. (sets x to nil and sets y to false)

Comment: @doesterr I don't think so. Given `options = {x: nil}`, `x = options.fetch(:x, 42)` definitely sets `x` to `nil`. That's the point of using `fetch`.

Comment: oops, you're right of course. don't know what I was thinking..

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
  def my_method(options = {})
   puts options[:var1] || ''
   puts options[:var2] || ''
   puts options[:var3] || ''
  end
```

call using

```
my_method(var1:999, var3: 123)
```

or

```
my_method(var1:999)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also play with something like this:

```
def method(data)
    defaults = {var2: 1, var3: 10}
    (@var1, @var2, @var3) = defaults.merge(data).values_at(:var1, :var2, :var3)
    p @var1, @var2, @var3
end

method(var1: 999, var3: 123)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby 2.0.0](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/) is released, now you can use named parameters.

```
def my_method(var1, var2: 1, var3: 10)
   puts var1, var2, var3
end

my_method(999, var3: 123)
```

The result:

```
999
1
123
```

Or another example:

```
def foo(str: "foo", num: 100)
  [str, num]
end

p foo(str: 'buz', num: 1) #=> ['buz', 1]
p foo(str: 'bar') # => ['bar', 100]
p foo(num: 2) # => ["foo", 2]
p foo # => ['foo', 100]
p foo(bar: 'buz') # => ArgumentError
```